# Angular provider not loading

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-service

i'm having some issues loading my providers.

setup is as follows:

- ng-view with main.html
- main.html has controller MainCtrl
- I have several directives which need access to the same data, so i'm using a provider to get it.
- I have one provider called ItemStorage that is a generic provider used to write, read, etc. anything based on parameters
- I have another provider that references ItemStorage that offers methods for getting specific things from ItemStorage called Data

When i reference Data in my controller (which references ItemStorage) I get a:
 "Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: ItemStorage"

but when I remove Data's reference to ItemStorage the application executes perfectly (minus some undefined errors caused by pointing to an empty object)

According to JSHint I have no syntax errors. Below is my providers file any help would be appreciated!

```
angular.module('myApp')
.provider('itemStorage', function(){
this.$get = function(){

    };
    //some other methods
})
.provider('Data',function(itemStorage){
var ItemStorage = {};
this.arrays = ItemStorage.arrays;

this.$get = function(){
    return {
                foo: function(){ return this.getItemFromStorage(
    };
};

this.getItemFromStorage = function(item){
    return Storage.getItem(item);
};
})
```

this is just a limited subset of the code.

While writing this up I have done some reading.. it is not possible to update a provider during run-time? can I not call a method to save something to local storage?

ultimately I need something that can hold data for the current user that is accessible and can be updated by any element to update every other element.. is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

When comparing to the documentation it would appear that you have not named your function and this could be the issue. So try something like:

```
angular.module('myApp').provider('itemStorage', function itemStorageProvider(){
```

this.$get = function(){

```
};
```

})

You probably also need to add this to you config, along the lines of

```
myApp.config(["itemStorageProvider", function(itemStorageProvider) {
```

}]);

Taken loosely from [Provider docs from angular website](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers)